# PHP JSON trying to get property of non-object error when looping

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get this Error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` each time the array is at index 0.

But works if there are more than 1 value in the array.

```
$jsonurl = "https://example.org/json_response/";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ( $json_output as $output ) {   
  echo $output->id;
}
```

Using `var_dump($json_output);` does returns the data.

**Edited**

```
array (size=2)
  'id' => string 'xYue78ee9es' (length=10)
  'username' => string 'peesBEE' (length=7)
```

But throws Error when I try to accessing the variable like this `echo $output->id;.`

Comment: `var_dump($output);` to see the content of each iteration. Given the Notice message, the first one isn't even an object

Comment: Can you show me $json_output array ?

Comment: yes i can see the content of each iteration, as normal. It actually works if there are more than 1 iteration

Comment: since you already set the flag to `true` on `json_decode`, you're already free of any objects inside your variable, so using the `->` arrow operator is unneeded

Comment: @Prakash, array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'xYue78ee9es' (length=10)

Comment: @Ghost, yes but lets assume the array has more than one return value, lets say returns "id" and "username", i would need using the -> arrow to specify which one to output

Comment: @user123451 as i have said earlier, once you've set that flag to `true`, what comes out of it is an array, treat it as such. posting your `var_dump($json_output)` would help those who answered below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have said already in the comments above, once you've set your `json_decode` flag as `true`, in turn, you'll get an array instead of an object.

Following in the comments:

> Can you show me $json_output array ? –  Prakash 
>   @Prakash, array (size=1) 'id' => string 'xYue78ee9es' (length=10) –  user123451

It seems its just a normal flat array, then treat it as such. Actually, you wouldn't need a foreach anymore. You can just access individual elements directly:

```
echo $json_output['id'];
echo $json_output['username'];
```

If you still would like to use a `foreach`, then it'll just traverse the first level, so you wouldn't need to put any index anymore:

```
foreach($json_output as $output) {
    echo $output;
    // no need for that ['id'] or ->id anymore
    // its just strings on $output
}
```

If you'd like to restrict some elements from getting echoed inside the `foreach` loop, simple `if` statement testing the keys should suffice:

```
foreach($json_output as $key => $output) {
    if($key === 'id') {
        echo $output; // echoes only id
    }
}
```

Comment: yea, but what if i just want to restrict  the output to just id alone. The code above displays both id and username, not specific on which data to output.

Comment: @user123451 are you referring to pointing to individual elements? just use `echo $json_output['id'];`

Comment: @user123451 if you'd want some filtering, just add an `if` inside the loop, check my revision

Answer (score 0):

Check json before foreach

```
if ($json_output && !empty($json_output)) {
    foreach ( $json_output as $output ) {   
        echo $output->id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$json_output` will be a php array, therefore you need to change

```
echo $output->id;
```

to

```
echo $output['id'];
```

**Edit**

Based on the `var_dump` you provided it seems that you need to remove the `foreach` loop and just use `echo $output['id']`

Comment: Ok, so now its giving me Error warning -  " Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' "

Comment: do a `var_dump($json_output)` and post the results